# How to await for a cljs.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel in clojurescript?

Tags: asynchronous, clojurescript

After making an cljs-http.client request like so: `(http/get ...)`, and trying to `prn` the response, I get the following:

```
cljs.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel
```

How to `await` (as in JS) this object to get the actual response?

-- Edit--

Doing

```
   (prn "result is " (go (let [result (<! (http/get "http://myurl.com"))]
                               result
                )))
```

Still gives me "result is cljs.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel"

whereas I'm expecting an object.

Answer (score 3):

> All HTTP functions in /cljs-http/ return a [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async)
>     channel. When a request has completed or failed it is put on that
>     channel. You can take the response from that channel with the `<!`
>     function *within* a `go` block.
>
> ```clj
>   (go (let [response (<! (http/get "https://api.github.com/users"
>                                    {:with-credentials? false
>                                     :query-params {"since" 135}}))]
>         (prn (:status response))
>         (prn (map :login (:body response)))))
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Source: https://github.com/r0man/cljs-http#async-response-handling